# What's all the blinking about?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, the-last-poets

*On the Subway* ("The Last Poets," 1970, track 02) ([genius.com link](https://genius.com/The-last-poets-on-the-subway-lyrics)) concludes with shouting the word "blink" a lot, and I'm not sure what it means.

On the surface level, I figure it might be describing the lights going past the train--but it could just as easily be the two men blinking furiously at each other. The verses describe both character and environment in a similar manner earlier in the piece. Or it could be something else entirely.

And whatever literal element the blinking is depicting in the scene described, what does it signify for the poem's theme?